Trouble displaying annotations for tags in Grafana panel
I'm currently working on displaying annotations in my Grafana panel and facing a bit of a challenge. I have a dataset in InfluxDB with the following fields: sensor_reading, and tags: sensor_name, sensor_discord. The sensor_discord tag is added only when a particular sequence is discordant. Now, I'm trying to display these discords using annotations.

Template Variable: sensor
InfluxDB Bucket: dynamic_discords
Measurement: loss_per_signal
Field: sensor_reading
Tag to Filter: sensor_discord

Approaches Tried:

Basic Annotation Query: Directly passed sensor_discord:discord tag but received no annotations.
I have also opened GitHub issue for this:

Github Issue

Filtered Query Using Template Variable: Used Flux query filtering discordant readings for the specified sensor; no annotations.
Alternative Filtering Approaches: Tried various modifications, but annotations still not displayed.

Additional Details:
Grafana Version: Grafana v10.4.0
InfluxDB Version: InfluxDB v2.7.5
Line Protocol Example:
Written data point: loss_per_signal,sensor_name=[22:12] sensor_reading=23170 1709598576170000000
Written data point: loss_per_signal,sensor_discord=discord,sensor_name=[3:1] sensor_reading=81629 1709598579170000000
Written data point: loss_per_signal,sensor_name=[9.26] sensor_reading=1 1709598580170000000
Written data point: loss_per_signal,sensor_name=[9.69] sensor_reading=0 1709598576170000000

I was trying to show discords dynamically using discords tag but it is not showing it.

I found a workaround for this issue:

I filtered the data using the sensor_discord tag.

Then, I created two queries:

The first query filters the discordant readings.
The second query retrieves all data.


After that, I used Field Overrides in Grafana:

I selected the fields returned by the query.
I set a red color for the discordant readings to make them stand out.



This approach worked perfectly!
